# RBAC Yii2 doesn't work with default roles

Tags: php, yii2, rbac

I'm following the Definitive Guide to Yii 2.0. In my application I have two roles: the admin, who can do everything and the viewer, who can do some actions that unregistered users can't do. I'm trying to use default roles functionality of Yii 2 RBAC, but it seems doesn't work. The user table in my database has a column named "role": for admin it's value set to 1 and for viewers = 2.

What I did:

/app/rbac/UserGroupRule.php

```
namespace app\rbac;

use Yii;
use yii\rbac\Rule;

class UserGroupRule extends Rule {
    public $name = 'userGroup';

    public function execute($user, $item, $params) {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            $group = Yii::$app->user->identity->role;
            if ($item->name === 'admin') {
                return $group == 1;
            } elseif ($item->name === 'viewer') {
                return $group == 1 || $group == 2;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

$auth = Yii::$app->authManager;

$rule = new \app\rbac\UserGroupRule;
$auth->add($rule);

$author = $auth->createRole('viewer');
$author->ruleName = $rule->name;
$auth->add($viewer);

$admin = $auth->createRole('admin');
$admin->ruleName = $rule->name;
$auth->add($admin);
$auth->addChild($admin, $viewer);
```

in my controller:

```
public function behaviors() {
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['admin'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['admin'],
                    'roles' => ['admin'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

When I try to access "admin" action, it says Forbidden #403, even when I'm an admin. How to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The user table in my database has a column named "role": for admin it's value set to 1 and for viewers = 2

That's not how it works unfortunately.
The rights/roles a user has are (by default) done via the `auth_assignment`-table.
Just add an entry in it:

```
INSERT INTO `auth_assignment` VALUES ("admin", <user-id>, NOW());
```

(be sure to change the user ID into whatever user you want to make admin.

That should solve your issue.

Edit (as I misread some of your question):

As per [this link](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/security-authorization.md#using-default-roles) you can indeed define default roles, but you have to make sure to also reconfigure your `authManager`-component in the configuration file to include the default roles:

```
'components' => [
    'authManager' => [
        // ...
        'defaultRoles' => ['admin', 'viewer'],
    ],
],
```

This list of roles indicate the permissions that always should be checked for every user, no matter if they have an entry in the `auth_assignment`-table or not.

Comment: should I make an entry in that table for every new user?

Comment: For all those requiring special roles, yes. You can also use the concept of default roles and have some assigned based on other criteria. I have updated my answer with a link.

Comment: uhm. I did the thing from that [link](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/security-authorization.md#using-default-roles) link as I mentioned in my question from the beginning and this is not working. you can see that my Rule-class is from that link. I mean, I did the thing with defaultRole from the start and this is not working

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I suspect that you might've forgotten to update the authManager configuration then to indicate it should always check the `admin` and `viewer` roles (the last piece of that paragraph)

Comment: Well, it's not the solution I wanted for, but it's probably the only solution yii can offer. Marked as solved.

Comment: The Definitive Guide to Yii 2.0 says that if developers want to use RBAC just with roles defined in one column in database (the last part of Authorization article) they just need to create a column with proper values and create a class file with rules. However, it's not working.

Comment: lol, so basically it is not working at all then... The way your rules are configured now it should only allow people with role `admin` in your `actionAdmin`-function in the controller. If you want all functions, just remove the "actions" line completely (not set means all actions). Other than that I would do a `var_dump()` in your `UserGroupRule`-class to make sure it is being called *and* works correctly.

Comment: only allow people with role admin in your actionAdmin-function - that's what I need. But when I'm admin, it says 403 Forbidden.

Comment: Then you have to figure out where it starts going wrong: add a `var_dump(Yii::$app->user->identity); die();` to `UserGroupRule::execute()` and see if it is being called. If that is not called there is something wrong with the setup even before that.

Comment: I've did that, the object is proper and Yii::$app->user->identity->role is returning the right value that stored in database row associated with currently logged in user.

Comment: I would suggest to try to change the access filter configuration variable by variable. Try all actions for logged in users first, then limit to the admin action, then try all actions with the admin role etc... Test in between and figure out what exactly fails. There are too many variables at this point.

Comment: I agree that this doesn't work. I feel that the document is wrong or incomplete when it comes to using groups. Calling \Yii::$app->user->can('whatever') will always return false regardless of what you have the execute() method return.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue with op. Finally made it work after tinkering with xdebug for a while.

I feel the official documentation on [default roles](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#using-default-roles) is missing a couple important points, I will summarize them below with some of my personal experiences. The project structure is based on Yii 2.0 Advanced Project Template

## Database

`user` table contains `id` and `group`. Where `group` is type `int`, 1 for `admin` and 2 for `author`

## Rules setup

Code simplified for clarity.

The rule class, where you put the actual rule logic.

> yii/console/controller/UserGroupRule.php

```
namespace app\rbac;

use Yii;
use yii\rbac\Rule;

/**
 * Checks if user group matches
 */
class UserGroupRule extends Rule
{
    public $name = 'userGroup';

    public function execute($user, $item, $params)
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            $group = Yii::$app->user->identity->group;
            if ($item->name === 'admin') {
                return $group == 1;
            } elseif ($item->name === 'author') {
                return $group == 1 || $group == 2;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now defining the roles..

> yii/console/controller/RbacController.php

```
namespace console\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\console\Controller;

class RbacController extends Controller
{
    public function actionInit()
    {
        $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;

        $rule = new \app\rbac\UserGroupRule;
        $auth->add($rule);

        $admin = $auth->createRole('admin');
        $admin->ruleName = $rule->name;
        $auth->add($admin);

        // define 'author' here...
    }
}
```

After you have this file ready, you should be able to run `./yii rbac/init` to generate the rule files:

- `console/rbac/items.php`
- `console/rbac/rules.php`

**Important: You need to place the generated files under your desired application folder, this is crucial. Other wise Yii 2.0 will not be able to pick up the rules. For example:** `yii/backend/rbac/`

## Controller and config setup

This is mostly identical to the documentation

> yii/commom/config/main.php

Add the following to the return array:

```
'authManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\rbac\PhpManager',
    'defaultRoles' => ['admin', 'author'], // your define roles
],
```

Now the fun part, under the controller class you would like to apply the rules

> yii/backend/controllers/SiteController.php

```
'access' => [
    'class' => AccessControl::className(),
    'rules' => [
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'actions' => [], // applies to all actions
            'roles' => ['admin'], // your defined roles
        ],
    ],
 ],
```

Up to this point, the rules should be working. Under your controller class, double check `Yii::$app->getAuthManager()` see if it contains your defined roles. If not, it means Yii did not pick up the rules correctly, please check previous steps again.